# vuetifyjs grid full height of columns and scroll on overflow

Tags: css, flexbox, vuetify.js, css-grid

I'm trying to fill out the `<v-content>` of a vuetifyjs app using its grid system. How can fill out columns to take up all available space and scroll overflow to certain cells?

[image]

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
})
```

```css
.grid-item-blue {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.grid-item-green {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.grid-item-pink {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-app-bar app fixed dark>
      <v-toolbar-title>Toolbar</v-toolbar-title>
    </v-app-bar>
    <v-content>
      <v-container fluid fill-height pa-0>
        <v-row no-gutters class="top-row">
          <v-col cols="9" class="grid-item-blue">fill screen</v-col>
          <v-col cols="3" class="grid-item-green">independent vertical scroll
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
        <v-row no-gutters class="bottom-row">
          <v-col cols="12" class="grid-item-pink">fixed height, always on bottom</v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
    <v-footer app dark>
      <span>Footer</span>
    </v-footer>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

This is how I have it working using css grid.

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-item-blue">fill screen</div>
    <div class="grid-item-green">independent vertical scroll</div>
    <div class="grid-item-pink">fixed height, always on bottom/</div>
</div>
```

```css
.grid {
  height: calc(100vh - 64px - 36px);
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 9fr 3fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 100px;
}

.grid-item-blue {
  background-color: lightblue;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

.grid-item-green {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.grid-item-pink {
  background-color: pink;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Make the container a flexbox container.
2. `flex-grow:0;` On the second element.
3. `flex-grow:1;` On the first element.

---

**Step 1:**

```
<v-container fluid fill-height pa-0>
```

Becomes:

```
<v-container fluid pa-0 class="d-flex flex-column flex-grow-1 fill-parent-height">
```

The last class, Is a simple custom class `.fill-parent-height{ height:100%; }`

---

**Step 2:**

```
<v-row no-gutters class="top-row">
```

Becomes:

```
<v-row no-gutters class="top-row flex-grow-1 flex-shrink-1">
```

---

**Step 3:**

```
<v-row no-gutters class="bottom-row">
```

Becomes:

```
<v-row no-gutters class="bottom-row flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0">
```

---

**Demo**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
})
```

```css
.grid-item-blue {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.grid-item-green {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.grid-item-pink {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100px;
}
.grid-item-green>p{
    height:9000px;
    border:10px solid;
    margin:20px;
}

.fill-parent-height {
  height: 100%;
}

.top-row{
    min-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-app-bar app fixed dark>
      <v-toolbar-title>Toolbar</v-toolbar-title>
    </v-app-bar>
    <v-content style="height:100vh">
      <!-- <v-container fluid fill-height pa-0> -->
      <v-container fluid pa-0 class="d-flex flex-column flex-grow-1 fill-parent-height">
        <!-- <v-row no-gutters class="top-row"> -->
        <v-row no-gutters class="top-row flex-grow-1 flex-shrink-1">
          <v-col cols="9" class="grid-item-blue fill-parent-height">
              fill screen
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="3" class="grid-item-green fill-parent-height">
              independent vertical scroll
              <p>long element</p>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
        <!-- <v-row no-gutters class="bottom-row"> -->
        <v-row no-gutters class="bottom-row flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0">
          <v-col cols="12" class="grid-item-pink">fixed height, always on bottom</v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
    <v-footer app dark>
      <span>Footer</span>
    </v-footer>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

---

**Edit:**

For the green Element to be scrollable we need to propagate the height down from the html or use viewport units on an arbitrary container element, I picked `<v-content style="height:100vh">`

*I update the demo above.*

Comment: @waspinator Don't edit answers to point out errors, You can leave a comment pointing out the problem accompanied by a link to a code snippet. I didn't even see the scrolling requirement. The answer has been updated.

Comment: sorry about that. Thanks for helping me figure this out.

Comment: Thank you dear lord, I was on my way to lose my mind.